# What is the proper syntax for running commands in CompizConfig Keybinds?

Tags: linux-mint, compiz

I am using linux mint

I want to set a keyboard shortcut to run `sharenix-section` everytime I press `<Control>semicolon`. My issue lies in the commands tab.

In command line, I know to do:

`cd Downloads` then

`sharenix-section`

But how do I write this into CompizConfig?

(I tried `cd Downloads && sharenix-section` but that seemed to have no effect)

Answer (score 0):

I think that is it better to go to 
System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts"